# Accept Multiple Data Types in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design, stored-procedures

I'll avoid any explanations and just get to the question. Is there a way to accept multiple data types for one parameter of a MySQL stored procedure?

I want to be able to accept both int and varchar-typed data for an IN parameter of the procedure. Is this possible?

I know this is not good practice (I'd never choose to do it myself) but some other developers are asking for me to support it for easy access.

Thanks,
Braeden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The closest way to do this is to set the parameter data type to text/varchar/etc and using dynamic SQL, which means [MySQL's Prepared Statement syntax](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html).

PS: Your developers deserve "the stink-eye" for their request

Comment: I agree; I should show them what you think of it.

And yeah, that's what I was thinking. I'll give it a whirl, but I'll most likely end up doing it the right way instead.

Thanks!